How do we evaluate pipelines efficiency? (build, release, test etc)
I am trying to generate a metric on how our current pipeline is performing, and seem to missing a framework for this, or feel like such a framework/metric already exist?
I am only interested in in the performance of pipeline, so I can give it a score and based on that score determine what need to be adjusted for.
For instance, a pipeline that is executed constantly should be fast?
A pipeline has to be reliable?
I need a general way to do pipeline analyis and determine how efficient our pipelines currently are, and based on that identify areas that need improvements.
Does such a metric exist?

I think you need to get clarity on what they mean by "efficient" in this context. Off the top of my head I would be looking at stuff like downloading images from the internet every run instead of caching, running tests in parrallel etc

Pipelines do the following:

Compile
Build
Deploy

Efficiency is about avoiding mistakes and wasting resources/effort/money.  It's also about consistency and repeatable results.
So, one could set up metrics for:

Duration of Compile, Build, Deploy steps
Counts of Failed compile/build/deployments
Frequency of builds deployments
Defect Count
Test breakage

An efficient pipeline would be good at:

Catching build errors
Check/run tests, failing when tests are broken
Run code coverage periodically, fail when coverage is not being met
Check for out-of-date components/security vulnerabilities
Running code analysis/linting
Have a high successful rate of deployment

It should stop the process if tests are breaking, vulnerabilities found, failed to compile, etc.   When automating these tasks, the process should be become more efficient, but one may add/enhance the pipeline for further efficiency.
If the pipeline does not do these things, bad builds can make their way into environment and waste people's time.  The more the pipeline can automate these tasks, the more efficient it will be.
Pipeline speed is secondary concern, which can always be improved.  For example, let's say the pipeline was downloading dependencies from the internet on every build, we might want to improve that by maintaining a local cache, so we don't have to fetch them every single time.
The real efficiency gains are from automating tasks to increase quality of software.
